# Classes that mimic the behavior of iPhone Application Settings...but within an app?

Tags: iphone, settings, appsettings

Has anyone written iPhone classes that mimic the behavior of the Application Settings? It would be nice to be able to define settings tables for use within my app using exactly the same XML structure, etc.

Comment: I may not have asked my question clearly enough. I don't want to actually use this for "Application Settings" that reside in Apple's Settings app. I can do that right now using the infrastructure that Apple provides.

What I'm curious about is a UI for settings-like-things that belong inside my app. Setting up grouped tables that allow display and editing of different kinds of object values is a lot of work. If there were classes--built along the lines of what Apple has done with Application Settings--it would make this work substantially easier.

Comment: Exactly such a library was described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043172/is-there-a-library-or-framework-for-setting-preferences-from-within-an-iphone-app. I extended my reply accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Is there a library or framework for setting preferences from within an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043172/is-there-a-library-or-framework-for-setting-preferences-from-within-an-iphone-app)

Esp. the [mySettings](http://bitbucket.org/karemorstol/mysettings/wiki/Home) library mentioned there:

> mySettings [...] uses a plist
>   configuration file like the one used
>   by the settings app, with some added
>   options.

[...]

> By default the settings themselves are
>   stored in the standard user defaults
>   object ([NSUserDefaults
>   standardUserDefaults]), but you can
>   use any object that supports key-value
>   coding. This enables you to use your
>   model classes directly in the settings
>   view.

Comment: Great, mySettings is (I think) exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The application settings (or NSUserDefaults) is essentially a glorified NSDictionary. You add objects to the settings and associate them with keys, so you can retrieve them later on.

If you want to do this, just create a class which wraps a singleton instance of a NSDictionary. That way you could reference it throughout your app like:

```
[[MyAppSettings sharedInstance] objectForKey:key];
```

Comment: By the way, if you want to save/restore the dictionary between app sessions, use - (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path, and - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag in order to convert back and forth from plist files.